# How to bind to an Image using a dynamic URL in WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, data-binding

I am new to WPF so hopefully I phrased the question correctly. What I'd like to do is bind my `<Image>` to an image online. However, the image I would like to bind to changes depending on the state of the application. For example, if I wanted to bind to an Employee selected from a list, I'd retrieve a base URL from my App.config and append the image name using the ID of the employee, like so:

```
var baseUrl = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BaseImageUrl"];
var imageUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}.jpg", baseUrl, employeeID);
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to do this declaratively in WPF. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a employee object in your code? If so you could expose a URI property which is built based on the employee ID of the object.

Otherwise could you have a asp.net page on your website which serves up a image (I have no idea if this will work, it is a idea though)

so have something like this in your xaml

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=EmployeeId, StringFormat='http://my.url.com/Image.aspx?employeeId={0}'}" />
```

Image.aspx would stream the image based on the employeeId get variable?

As I said there is probably a bit wrong with this but it could work, I think the URI property on a employee class would be the cleanest option though.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will help:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ImageSource x:Key="MyImage" Source="C:\Images\Default.jpg" />
</..>

<Image Source="{DynamicResource MyImage}" />
```

Then in your code-behind:

```
((ImageSource)this.Resources["MyImage"]).Source = "C:\Path\From\Config.jpg";
```

Comment: Can that filesystem path be substituted for a URL?  I think that's what the original question required (and I'm curious).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Great suggestion. However, I was hoping there might be a way to do this declaratively (without having to go into codebehind). Am I hoping for too much? :)

Comment: Also, I would stay away from dynamic resources.

Comment: @daub815 why would you stay away from dynamic resources?

Comment: It uses up more resources, so you should probably only use it when you absolutely need it.