# How to solve hard issue about Cannot deserialize the current (eg {“name”:“value”}) by using newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, spotify

**The classes:**

```
public class TrackSpotify
{
    public class ExternalUrls
    {
        public string spotify { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string album_type { get; set; }
        public List<string> available_markets { get; set; }
        public ExternalUrls external_urls { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Image> images { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    public class Albums
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public object previous { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Albums albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The json string**

```
 {
  "albums" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases?offset=0&limit=20",
    "items" : [ {
      "album_type" : "single",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "ES", "FR", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/60mvULtYiNSRmpVvoa3RE4"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/60mvULtYiNSRmpVvoa3RE4",
      "id" : "60mvULtYiNSRmpVvoa3RE4",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/8642802d13a53541e313781c34521a0d33099aac",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/631ee4d5160303af86751587457b1b00957e0519",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/d7b7140400d985d1294d7b044da1b5b4bfc0ae69",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "We Are One (Ole Ola) [The Official 2014 FIFA World Cup Song]",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:60mvULtYiNSRmpVvoa3RE4"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/4JXziyWNlxM4oPw34PMjVj"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4JXziyWNlxM4oPw34PMjVj",
      "id" : "4JXziyWNlxM4oPw34PMjVj",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/47c6249a3d514752fc783e64a2f47611bce66a4b",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/a22dbdd2595f1144890eb269bb93cc79142f2767",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c1bd45015d6a1245603a88e03d336992f5d653a2",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "A13",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:4JXziyWNlxM4oPw34PMjVj"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/1SIpLwZu1R69coxKMH06kw"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1SIpLwZu1R69coxKMH06kw",
      "id" : "1SIpLwZu1R69coxKMH06kw",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c65ef9bb11bcd9d06aa710866fb3440291c5f9ea",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/8db5eeba539b7eabe7599e13e7bd83b8ec9f98bb",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/abfb50b9844def2e40afac4059da71d658845ab2",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "May Death Never Stop You",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:1SIpLwZu1R69coxKMH06kw"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "single",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/5qZNAZ5xJCUAiyYoETU0aj"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5qZNAZ5xJCUAiyYoETU0aj",
      "id" : "5qZNAZ5xJCUAiyYoETU0aj",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/86c15f11c44726c52df044882e39e6c4d168f8a8",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/f7e52154d6ea994ea9e78dd8b1ab0d37417934ef",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2a5c218cb7e524c5bd95b938b3553905311705da",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Keep Watch",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:5qZNAZ5xJCUAiyYoETU0aj"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/5ZzFFF7wSMmGaIWjAHElnW"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5ZzFFF7wSMmGaIWjAHElnW",
      "id" : "5ZzFFF7wSMmGaIWjAHElnW",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/aa1d1cf0d70fb29b4ae575f10d2ac8acc88413f5",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/aed60ab4e13c6cd781df8dcd2375c2b186ae1991",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/058e4170c906814ee70fb51ae1d84d09d5244979",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "By Any Means",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:5ZzFFF7wSMmGaIWjAHElnW"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "single",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/0LKHTm8YOJH9ygGm8DWv40"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0LKHTm8YOJH9ygGm8DWv40",
      "id" : "0LKHTm8YOJH9ygGm8DWv40",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/6b2eea62c1a6f986824e25ff4e0f072c515a9988",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/f9a46fb4f6f4ca0117c2d1ab530a36958921720b",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/06e3464983b24b9957828d10b6c2a34c6dddae9c",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Depth of My Soul (feat. Shana Halligan)",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:0LKHTm8YOJH9ygGm8DWv40"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/1dKh4z5Aayt8FFDWjO5FDh"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dKh4z5Aayt8FFDWjO5FDh",
      "id" : "1dKh4z5Aayt8FFDWjO5FDh",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b2602ba2bd35dca1cc2903d58429a9379b342bf3",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/8b86d8c65c01dacc92305003559db960e36a9614",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/3eb58e564cc6ede9ac234c293e905e166cefa1b2",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Singles",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:1dKh4z5Aayt8FFDWjO5FDh"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/33jUyJOx4j6BWJ7VkzWoth"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/33jUyJOx4j6BWJ7VkzWoth",
      "id" : "33jUyJOx4j6BWJ7VkzWoth",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/e35451b38b162c4a8665b77e729c53a2437d6f74",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/f5baa64ff1928f27163516658b8301b92e54c80a",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/41f4c456d66bc81d4e10d502d707fb778c431798",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Out Among The Stars",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:33jUyJOx4j6BWJ7VkzWoth"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/4kE1w1zgP6Ag6Ojbuxzk7l"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4kE1w1zgP6Ag6Ojbuxzk7l",
      "id" : "4kE1w1zgP6Ag6Ojbuxzk7l",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c9eca97fd2817f349737dfe2aa672929759a556b",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b131664fc60fc781b5bfe41a41763d4176abfdcb",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/5d2a8eeb9732f68c09c8c582ee5d028091fe1abf",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Underneath the Rainbow (Bonus Track Version)",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:4kE1w1zgP6Ag6Ojbuxzk7l"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/6RCOAR93Gi157qwW771xFG"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6RCOAR93Gi157qwW771xFG",
      "id" : "6RCOAR93Gi157qwW771xFG",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/590d34233a0ef309d2c83213fb20cdef7e7804c6",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/5bceabff51f4e0366fa7e05bfc92e3f8a73e157f",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/32d480d47b3f0d0687c7d6cb362f7246b35fb62e",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Kiss Me Once (Special Edition)",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:6RCOAR93Gi157qwW771xFG"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "single",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/14GhiNSb8mH3sOnersqp28"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/14GhiNSb8mH3sOnersqp28",
      "id" : "14GhiNSb8mH3sOnersqp28",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/ceabefd7b5c7c1a4a4a550de823289810b14b7dd",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/398e5dda368c86337c8240dd2e6fa015ae576ce2",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/e73d5b0fb22ae7e0ceb66155a7dc82f5512f9005",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "FALLINLOVE2NITE",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:14GhiNSb8mH3sOnersqp28"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/7rf1qZJ6hGSlPN7K9ShsVV"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7rf1qZJ6hGSlPN7K9ShsVV",
      "id" : "7rf1qZJ6hGSlPN7K9ShsVV",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/9ab61dfa896d1431af5cddcb2bb9dba471103bb0",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/fd6fe6aa26f835e85fc8b555f2ed86a36d62ca33",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c00728e445db587f47d8f4161319d83e5b2fe33c",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Recess",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:7rf1qZJ6hGSlPN7K9ShsVV"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/1YPlEB0kZ4SOyT2kBLgINR"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1YPlEB0kZ4SOyT2kBLgINR",
      "id" : "1YPlEB0kZ4SOyT2kBLgINR",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/baca3f284d82c0b10286dfdd0727b96b7744caf5",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/f0cea1f04f0a442049aad5047d06a4948752d94e",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/233aafd9f55291c1103ed69b821af3521d4f97ce",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Love Letters",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:1YPlEB0kZ4SOyT2kBLgINR"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/2BQejnIGjuFugsT71hhOG3"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2BQejnIGjuFugsT71hhOG3",
      "id" : "2BQejnIGjuFugsT71hhOG3",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b02ee9ec0e8eade076bc2358cba1e22921de956d",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/1e92081774a2150269dc23ee02bd643c8e5c1bb5",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/113ff50a0e7d0a52de712314e1bf4e66e1460598",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "The Take Off And Landing Of Everything",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:2BQejnIGjuFugsT71hhOG3"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "CA", "US" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/13xRSfodlL3UtG3xSyL8u2"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/13xRSfodlL3UtG3xSyL8u2",
      "id" : "13xRSfodlL3UtG3xSyL8u2",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2ab5e967f8979027fbe7ae7508aaa216f98ebbd9",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/0b87d1fbca3b4bf8a1df3bff69c49083bc0363ba",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/221626b9dc42c9a8e75d53a277c601824f173c49",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "No Mythologies to Follow (Deluxe)",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:13xRSfodlL3UtG3xSyL8u2"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/7lAYJiypiPbCDvjKOBX1TV"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7lAYJiypiPbCDvjKOBX1TV",
      "id" : "7lAYJiypiPbCDvjKOBX1TV",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/915c9f12ef6479d885ae3f6de2dedafb70494d20",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/aba9cf39c84a1444420b230f0e6b851ec4db8f08",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/107b06d55ea161a15a21dec478d5aa1d0befaa40",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Atlas",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:7lAYJiypiPbCDvjKOBX1TV"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "single",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/4cCfFozyo6JC8acN8uIP7u"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4cCfFozyo6JC8acN8uIP7u",
      "id" : "4cCfFozyo6JC8acN8uIP7u",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/95f5cbdb03db43c16046562c5f85cc2e3f77b596",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c950057b00130fb061e801b45aea6cc45dba1bc3",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/53c5c7fbda7527abb8635e7af36af4e333f01e22",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Magic",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:4cCfFozyo6JC8acN8uIP7u"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/4JHtCtKG5CXJAXYLJtKUEE"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4JHtCtKG5CXJAXYLJtKUEE",
      "id" : "4JHtCtKG5CXJAXYLJtKUEE",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c61a960d6110e259eb26a8a48d39b5b43b61bcdf",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/e504411141d5dd4742d41245e9821d6da9079bc5",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b4af49db137f7862cef31d64b4ab9c7f14475467",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Somebody's Party - EP",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:4JHtCtKG5CXJAXYLJtKUEE"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AR", "AU", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CL", "CO", "CR", "DO", "EC", "GT", "HK", "HN", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PY", "SG", "SV", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/0Cvy3SH2exFvz8WIX68HSZ"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0Cvy3SH2exFvz8WIX68HSZ",
      "id" : "0Cvy3SH2exFvz8WIX68HSZ",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/3d0b40dbf4ed6318b2bbe87d83a9bcbf39fcc45d",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/bc2bd24632e69303590c47a60c0d3b7e73ad641a",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/79b3b1df664940f0352a7214e1260603124cc590",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Spotify Sessions - Live at Warped Tour 2013",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:0Cvy3SH2exFvz8WIX68HSZ"
    }, {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/5OlEEw6gIk32eMhOqRlfGu"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5OlEEw6gIk32eMhOqRlfGu",
      "id" : "5OlEEw6gIk32eMhOqRlfGu",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 636,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/5211638dd177a7a1266b32c896dc8b42c2b1df42",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 298,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/428b45010d16b41c53260724d447810199cb3d11",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/a6ee613798ecb589b02339bb5749194e9da3e547",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "Bob Dylan - 30th Anniversary Concert Celebration (Deluxe Edition) [Remastered]",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:5OlEEw6gIk32eMhOqRlfGu"
    } ],
    "limit" : 20,
    "next" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases?offset=20&limit=20",
    "offset" : 0,
    "previous" : null,
    "total" : 119
  }
}
```

**The code**

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> QueryTrack()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases?client_id=" + API_key + "&country=US&offset=0&limit=20&access_token=....h";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    HttpResponseMessage v = new HttpResponseMessage();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
public async void load() 
{
    var query = await queryTrack.QueryTrack();
    var arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TrackSpotify.Item>>(query);//Errors
    spotifyItems.ItemsSource = arrays;
}
```

I was trying this with no results.

**Other things that I tried:**

```
List<NewReleaseSpotify.Item> arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewReleaseSpotify.Item>>(query);

List<NewReleaseSpotify.RootObject> arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewReleaseSpotify.RootObject>>(query)
```

with error: Cannot deserialize the current json object (eg {“name”:“value.....

**and**

```
var arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string,NewReleaseSpotify.Item>>(query);

var arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewReleaseSpotify.Item>(query);
```

with: NewReleaseSpotify.RootObject null.

Comment: I have literally no idea what you are asking? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your json string represents singular object, so you can't deserialize it to a collection data type such as `List<T>`. Try to simply deserialize to `NewReleaseSpotify.RootObject` instead :

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewReleaseSpotify.RootObject>(query);
```

... then `Console.WriteLine(root.albums.href);` successfully prints `https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases?offset=0&limit=20` for me. See **[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B3kYwm)**.

Comment: Yes it print https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases?offset=0&limit=20 but how to get data out

Comment: spotifyItems.ItemsSource = arrays.albums.items; Ok but How binding images to xmal?

Comment: @satbarron That should go in a [separate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts), and I can see you did that already.

Answer (score 1):

The full error you get was self explanatory :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestProject.TrackSpotify+RootObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

I have the following code working without any troubles:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "you json string here";
            var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrackSpotify.RootObject>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
        }
    }
```

[Fiddler link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5IlOydw8Iu)

Comment: Ok but spotifyItems.ItemsSource = arrays; show error up. arrays get 20 items.

Comment: How to bind images width,... to xaml?

Comment: Whats the error? And What and Where is the exception.

Comment: I fixed but I dont know to bind image to xaml?arrays.albums.items

Comment: Is this your question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179386/getting-issue-on-json

Comment: Please post that as another question or search the web or SO

Comment: Yes, but I removed it

Comment: This is for a start => http://stackoverflow.com/a/21789092/1155650